# How do I add an application tile for QGIS to the Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, qgis

I have succeeded at adding a qgis environment to Anaconda Navigator.  I have installed 3.34.2 , the latest from QGIS. I can launch a command prompt and enter 'qgis' and the app itself appears functional. So far so good.

What I really want is an app tile to show up in the navigator itself for QGIS.  How do I go about doing this.....?????

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\static\content\external_apps.yml (or your local user folder equivalent).

Add a new entry to the metadata, using one of the existing tile texts as a template.

Example:

```
glueviz:
  display_name: Glueviz
  description: >
    Multidimensional data visualization across files. Explore relationships within and among related datasets.
  image_path: glueviz-icon-1024x1024.png
```